# How can I change the height for a psd file?

Tags: grid, psd

I'm working on designing a website with photoshop, the problem is that the height limit of the PSD is reached.. and I'm still not finished

So how can I increase the size of the height without effecting the elements inside ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using canvase size you want to increase you page height
path : image=>canvase size (shortcut:Alt + Cntr + C)
than using arrow left,top,right and bottom specified page increase